# Mongoengine object level security with Pyramid

Tags: acl, pyramid, mongoengine

I've been trying to figure out how to do the object level security with mongoengine and haven't found any good solution.

Should I be using factories or something else? Somehow the **getitem**-function is never called, so I can't really do a thing in there. Also models ACL seems to be ignored completely. Is it possibility to validate the permissions of the user in model-level?

Case:

1. User is able to add a car.
2. User has a car and only he should be able to modify it.

config:

```
config = Configurator(settings=settings,
                          root_factory=RootFactory,
                          authentication_policy=AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy,
                          authorization_policy=ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
                          )
```

Model:

```
    class Car(Document):
        """Car model"""
        @property
        def __acl__(self):
            return [
                (Allow, self.owner, 'modify'),
                (Allow, 'group:admins', 'edit')
            ]
        make = StringField(required=False)
        model = StringField()
        owner = ReferenceField('User')
```

Factories:

```
    class RootFactory(object):
        """Root factory"""
        def __init__(self, request):
            self.__acl__ = [(Allow, Authenticated, 'create'),
                            (DENY_ALL)
                            ]

    class CarFactory(object):
        __acl__ = [
            (Allow, Authenticated, 'create'),
            (Allow, 'self.owner', 'modify'),
            (DENY_ALL)
        ]

        def __init__(self, request):
            self.request = request

        def __getitem__(self, key):
            user = USERS[key]
            user.__parent__ = self
            user.__name__ = key
            return user
```

Routes:

```
    config.add_route('saveCar', '/car/save/', factory=CarFactory)
```

View:

```
    @view_config(route_name='saveCar',
                 request_method='POST',
                 permission='modify')
    def saveCar(request):
        """Save car functions"""
```

Comment: Did you notice http://michael.merickel.org/projects/pyramid_auth_demo/object_security.html ???

Comment: Yes I did.

I think that I'll relay the response to model and handle permission checks on CRUD-actions.